# find all but skip one folder

Tags: linux, find, skip

I have a command that looks through all my sub folders for files, however I want it to skip a folder from the search and I'm not sure what is the right way to do this:

```
find -name '*.avi' -o -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*.mp4' -o -name '*.vob'
```

I want it to not look into the folder name: secure

I tried:

```
find -name '*.avi' -o -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*.mp4' -o -name '*.vob' --skip 'secure'
```

but it does not work.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: if you want everything but secure maybe  -prune can be helpful but in advanced you must use awk

Comment: find -name '*.avi' -o -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*.mp4' -o -name '*.vob'  -not -iwholename'secure' this be helpful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no --skip argument in GNU find.  But you can do what you want using the `-path` and `-prune` expressions.  The syntax is a little weird: you use `-path ./secure -prune` as a term  which you then OR with the rest of the expression.  So in your case:

`find . -name '*.avi' -o [...] -o -path ./secure -prune`

Note that this will still return the directory `./secure` in the results, but nothing inside it.

Comment: this works wonders! very easy to understand for someone like me that has a huge learning curve! thank you very much!

Comment: Can I also use this to skip any files that has the word "secure" in it as well?

Answer (score 1):

What about the following?

```
find \( -name '*.avi' -o -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*.mp4' -o -name '*.vob' \) -a -not -path './secure*'
```

Comment: This works, but note that it still traverses the ./secure tree, rejecting all files and directories underneath.  I like -prune for that reason.

Comment: Not only it's more efficient but using `-prune` seems a more cleaner and elegant solution also.